# Unable to insert data into mysql using android emulator via php

Tags: php, android, mysql, xml

Actually, am newbie in android and trying to insert record into mysql table using android via php page. Am using wamp server but. I using IP address 10.0.2.2 instead of 127.0.0.1 and I also used IP address with 10.0.0.2:8676 for my port number also but none of them is working and I always find this is error Invalid IP address. Am unable to understand where am I wrong. Although this code is working on live server host and values are inserting into live server but not in localhost. Am using wamp server and my Operating System is Windows XP 3 . Am using Eclipse . Android SDK 17 android version 4.2. Below is my code:

Thanks in advance.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

String name;
String id;
InputStream is=null;
String result=null;
String line=null;
int code;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(com.example.buddyproject.R.layout.activity_main);

    final EditText e_id=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    final EditText e_name=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    Button insert=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    insert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        id = e_id.getText().toString();
        name = e_name.getText().toString();

        insert();
    }
});
}

public void insert()
{
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id",id));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name",name));

    try
    {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/androidtest/insert.php");
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); 
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
        Log.e("pass 1", "connection success ");
}
    catch(Exception e)
{
        Log.e("Fail 1", e.toString());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid IP Address",
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}     

    try
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
        (new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result = sb.toString();
    Log.e("pass 2", "connection success ");
}
    catch(Exception e)
{
        Log.e("Fail 2", e.toString());
}     

try
{
        JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result);
        code=(json_data.getInt("code"));

        if(code==1)
        {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Inserted Successfully",
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Sorry, Try Again",
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
        Log.e("Fail 3", e.toString());
}
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

```
$host='localhost';
$uname='root';
$pwd='';
$db="test";

$con = mysql_connect($host,$uname,$pwd) or die("connection failed");
mysql_select_db($db,$con) or die("db selection failed");


$id=$_REQUEST['id'];
$name=$_REQUEST['name'];

$flag['code']=0;

    $sql="INSERT INTO sample (id,name)VALUES('$id','$name')";



 if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
{
    $flag['code']=1;
    echo"hi";
}
print(json_encode($flag));
mysql_close($con);
```

Comment: did u tested ur php script?

Comment: Yes I have tested my php code and it is working

Comment: ok and how abt response from ur app when posting to php?

Comment: It is executing this (catch) part instead of try catch(Exception e)
{
        Log.e("Fail 1", e.toString());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid IP Address",
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your ip in this line

```
 HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/androidtest/insert.php");
```

Open cmd-type ipconfig -hit enter.
Get IPv4 address usually starts with 192.X

[image]

Change ip in your code. It should work

Answer (score 0):

Your try statements are catching **every** exception. You should not do this and you certainly can't conclude 'Invalid IP address' in the first block.

It's much more likely that you are throwing a [NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html) because you are trying to do networking on the UI thread. You shouldn't do that either. You should delegate the network code to a different thread or run it in an AsyncTask.